# Angular Gulp with Nginx on AWS on Ubuntu

Tags: python, angularjs, django, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have been developing a website that has a structure as follows -

- Django rest app for backend that serves json to the front-end according to what has been requested.
- AngularJS app for the frontend which requests those apis.

Now both backend and frontend are not coupled in any way and locally I used to **manage.py runserver** the backend and **gulp serve** the frontend.

I am moving to development now and I have set up nginx with aws to run django and cater to api requests, which is working fine.

But for the frontend, I am confused as-

- What gulp serve does is, it injects all the scss and dependencies and starts up the app. How would I start the app using nginx(basically gulp serve)?

How would I get django and angular runnung on nginx on the same instance?
It would be nice if someone post some examples too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make Django serve a base template through a view.

Now this base template should contain the main angular app. It will also contain all the angular dependencies such as the libraries and your controllers/service/directives etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularApp">

{% block head %}
<head>

    

    {% block angular_requirements %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}node_modules/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}angular_apps/dashboard/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}angular_apps/controllers/dealController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}angular_apps/controllers/catController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}angular_apps/dashboard/controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}angular_apps/dashboard/services.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}angular_apps/dashboard/utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}angular_apps/dashboard/filters.js"></script>
    {% endblock angular_requirements %}


</head>
{% endblock head %}

<body>

   

</body>

</html>
```

Keep in mind that this base template will reside in your Django templates folder and all the angular file will reside in your static folder.

Now, the base template is served with your Django view and your static files are to be served via nGinx.

You'll have to add a static rule in your nGinx conf:

```
location /static/ {
         alias  <path-to-collect-static-folder>;
    }
```

So your folder structure can look something like this:

```
Django-app/
    app/
    templates/
        base.html
    static/
        node_modules/ # will contain all libraries
        angular_app/
            app.js
            controllers.js
```

Here is a project that has Django backend with an Angular frontend:
https://github.com/aliasav/coder-submissions

Comment: I have hundreds of controllers, services and directives, is there a better way?

Comment: If you have that many controllers, than maybe you can have different apps for different pages. However, this is a tested architecture for decently sized SPAs that I have been using for quite some time. So the page load time maybe a little high but there are ways to reduce that as well

Comment: Not necessarily, you could have a gulp task that inserts the required dependencies. You can have as much level of automation that you need, the idea here is to focus on the architecture that allows Django to load a base_template and then load your angular app

Comment: I understand the above mentioned answer. The confusion that I have is how to run gulp automatically to insert all the dependencies?

Comment: So you could use ansible tasks that call gulp tasks on deployments. In gulp, you can write a simple task that writes to all files in a particular folder (say controllers) to the base.html

Comment: Is there an example on how to write such tasks? Do I have to use supervisor to call such tasks?

Comment: Kindly post a different question for these queries. Also you don't need supervisor to call these tasks, look into ansible for deployments (https://www.ansible.com/). Ansible shall be calling those tasks.

Comment: If you could post an example of how to automate this, it'd be really helpful !